# woocommerce product category page showing not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on wordpress woocommerce site. I want to set logic user can not see product category or subcategory or product page without login,it will redirected to login page.
My code below

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

But after logged in when go to product category page, it will redirected to login page. I also checked it by debug, product category page showing not logged in.I can not understand after logged in when go to product category page, why showing not logged in?
Please help me with possible solutions.
Thanks..

Comment: Your code should work. I tested and works for me.

Comment: It is working into localhost but not in server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to the `woocommerce_myaccount_page_id` option.
Try to get it via slug *(in case the page slug is "my-account")*:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-account/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

or via the id of the **My Account** page:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        $my_account_page_id = 2;
        wp_redirect( get_page_link( $my_account_page_id )  );
        exit();
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*